# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') - useQuery

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am Using https://swapi.dev/ form Api's calls but its throwing "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" error.

Please check the below error and code

[image]

```
import React  from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import Planet from './Planet';

const fetchPlanets = async (key, page) => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=${page}`);
    return res.json();
}

const Planets = () => {
    const { data, status } = useQuery(['planets', 2], fetchPlanets);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Planets</h2>
            {status === 'error' && (<div>Error While fetching the data !!!</div>)}
            {status === 'loading ' && (<div>Loading............</div>)}
            {status === 'success' && (<div>{data.results.map(planet => <Planet key={planet.name} planet={planet} />)}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Planets;
```

Thanks
In Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKING FINE FOR ME :) newer versions of react query came So we need to make some little changes

```
const fetchPlanets = async (page) => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=${page}`);
    return res.json();
};
```

if wan to set data :

```
 const {data, status} = useQuery(['planets', page], () => fetchPlanets(page));
```

Answer (score 1):

As your screenshot show, the api delivers a `404 - Not found` response. Because you're using `fetch`, erroneous status codes are not transformed to failed promises automatically, so you have to do that manually by checking for `res.ok`. This is documented in the react-query docs under [Usage with fetch and other clients that do not throw by default](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-functions#usage-with-fetch-and-other-clients-that-do-not-throw-by-default).

So you are effectively getting a successful query with `undefined` as `data`, which is why you have the runtime error.

To find out why you request `?page=undefined`, we have to take a look at how you invoke `fetchPlanets`:

```
useQuery(['planets', 2], fetchPlanets);
```

you're passing `fetchPlanets` as `queryFn`, but the signature doesn't match what react-query expects:

```
const fetchPlanets = async (key, page) => {
```

Since v3, the query key is no longer "spread" as arguments in your function. This is documented in the [v3 migration guide](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3#query-key-partspieces-are-no-longer-automatically-spread-to-the-query-function). Instead, the query function now receives a `queryContext` - an object which contains the key. So you can either change your signature to:

```
const fetchPlanets = async ({ queryKey }) => {
```

and then use `queryKey[1]` to access the `page`, or, you use an inline function:

```
const fetchPlanets = async (page) => {
...
}

useQuery(['planets', page], () => fetchPlanets(page))
```